# BeautifulSoup find_all <td>'s except last four ones

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the text form all the cells, except from the last four cells. Is there a way to do this or should I try to find another solution to my problem? My code is currently extremely simple:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.example.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for link in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(link.string)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns a `ResultSet` object which is based on `list`:

```
class ResultSet(list):
    """A ResultSet is just a list that keeps track of the SoupStrainer
    that created it."""
    def __init__(self, source, result=()):
        super(ResultSet, self).__init__(result)
        self.source = source
```

[Slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) it:

```
for link in soup.find_all("td")[:-4]: 
    print(link.string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this iteratively, without loading the whole set of results into a list, you can. Just keep a queue of 4 links, and when the queue is full, pop and print the oldest before pushing the newest. Like this:

```
q = collections.deque(maxlen=4)
for link in soup.find_all("td"):
    if len(q) == q.maxlen:
        print(q.popleft())
    q.push(link.string)
```

And of course you can wrap this up in a function:

```
def butlast(iterable, n):
    q = collections.deque(maxlen=n)
    for value in iterable:
        if len(q) == q.maxlen:
            yield q.popleft()
        q.push(value)

for link in butlast(soup.find_all("td"), 4):
    print(link.string)
```

But really, if you've got enough memory to store the whole Soup, you've probably got enough memory to store a list of a few dozen nodes, so it's a list easier to just use the list. As it turns out, `soup.find_all()` already returns a list (well, a subclass of `list`), so all you have to do it:

```
for link in soup.find_all("td")[:-4]:
    print(link.string)
```

But, even if that weren't true, you could just make a list to slice it:

```
for link in list(soup.find_all("td"))[:-4]:
    print(link.string)
```